# What is meant by "dynamic tag" referred to in this text:

Tags: c, linux, gcc, debian, elf

Copied from http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/LibraryPathOverview :

> any directory named in the (deprecated) DT_RPATH dynamic tag of the requesting object, or, recursively, any parent object (note that DT_RPATH is ignored if DT_RUNPATH is also present)

I can't seem to find the definition of a dynamic tag anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every dynamically linked ELF image (executable of type `ET_EXEC` or library of type `ET_DYN`) has a dynamic table (which you can see via `objdump -p a.out` or `readelf -d a.out`). Each entry in a table contains a set of `Elf32_Dyn` or `Elf64_Dyn` entries, and each entry has a `d_tag` and `d_value` members. Documentation [here](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_cprog/OF_DynSection.html).

The `dynamic tag` is the `d_tag` entry, which is just an integer tag (`DT_NEEDED`, `DT_STRTAB`, etc.) describing what the `d_value` of this particular entry in the table represents.

Dynamic loader uses the dynamic table to load ELF image, find libraries that are needed by it (using `DT_NEEDED` and `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` entries), initialize it (using `DT_INIT` or `DT_INIT_ARRAY`), find symbols in it (`DT_SYMTAB`, `DT_STRTAB`, `DT_HASH`), relocate it, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It simply refers to the entries in the *Dynamic Section* (DT probably stands for *Dynamic Table* or something).

You can see them with the command:

```
$ objdump -p program
```